# How to reduce time complexity for the following code?

Tags: python, puzzle

I was trying the [problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/trapping-rain-water/0/) on Geeks for Geeks. I came up with an approach as a two-array solution, the first array "arr1" holds the maximum height till now from the front while "arr2" holds the maximum height from the back till now ("arr2" is being filled from he end).
For calculating the answer I doe the following operation while iterating the 3 arrays:

```
 ans += min(arr1[i], arr2[i]) - arr[i]
```

This solutions works but on final submission gives TLE error.
Please help me to identify the more optimal solution.

Code:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
n=int(input())
arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
arr1=[0]*n
arr2=[0]*n
arr1[0]=arr[0]
arr2[n-1]=arr[n-1]
j=n-2
ans = 0
for i in range(1,n):
    arr1[i]=(max(arr1[i-1],arr[i]))
    arr2[j]=(max(arr2[j+1],arr[n-1-i]))
    j-=1
for i in range(n):
    ans += min(arr1[i], arr2[i]) - arr[i]

# print(arr)
# print(arr1)
# print(arr2)
print(ans)
```

Is there any method that enables me to calculate the "ans" in the same loop? Or any other method to optimize the answer?

Comment: You could reduce the complexity from 2N to O(N), by shifting boundaries on both sides and adding water one column at a time.  Since you know that for any two boundaries, that at minimum the water trapped for the column next to boundary must be at least the height of the smaller boundary, you can just move the boundary from the side with the smaller maximum column.  I'm not sure if this will be enough to pass TLE though, since 2N to N isn't really significant.

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of log N algo, that lets you you skip over columns if you can find boundary columns that fit a certain condition.  I can't think of any further shortcuts, since if there are any columns that are larger in between, you have to scan them all in order to know for sure there isn't' a larger range of columns to account for.

Comment: Above will work if TLE takes into account space complexity, since the only space it consumes are a couple integers (so it's O(1) space, while yours is O(2N)).

Answer (score 0):

Right now your time complexity is O(2n) which is the same as O(n). Even if you were to calculate everything in a single loop, your time complexity will still be O(n).

Comment: So any idea for a diff answer? A new approach maybe.